# DraftJs with react, decorator not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, draftjs

im trying to create my own decorator, but its not working.
its soppuse to do some styling to the word im inputing in my search field

**input field**

```
 <Editor
              editorState={this.props.editorState}
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
      
          />
          <div>
            <input
                value={this.props.searchState}
                onChange={this.props.onChangeSearch}
                placeholder="Search..."
            />
```

**my Decorator**

```
const generateDecorator = (highlightTerm) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(highlightTerm, 'g');
  return new CompositeDecorator([{
    strategy: (contentBlock, callback, contentState) => {
      if (highlightTerm !== '') {
        findWithRegex(regex, contentBlock, callback);
      }
    },
    component: SearchHighlight,
  }]);
};
```

**my "Styling" component**

```
class SearchHighlight extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <span style={{fontSize: '32', backgroundColor: 'green', width: 40, height: 40}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
```

**implementing the decorator**

```
  onChangeSearch = (e) => {
    const search = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      search,
      editorState: EditorState.set(this.state.editorState, {decorator: generateDecorator(search)}),
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you please put your code in codepen and provide link to it ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?